# How audio analysis can help improving pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm sorry if it's inappropriate to post this kind of question here but appreciate answering or recommending where to post. Being an engineer who know a little bit about audio analysis I wonder if audio analysis software can help me to improve English pronunciation. Does anybody know about this kind of technique? I tried [Praat](https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) but could only find some tutorials about software.

Comment: (Not sure if this is on topic or not; the Linguistics board is another possibility.) It's normally better to have a human listener who has some knowledge of the language, but I guess in some situations audio analysis would be better than nothing. Certainly, language learning apps like Duolingo use speech recognition software to help learners, which is somewhat related.

Comment: The ears of a *human* listener are "attuned" specifically to recognise and differentiate the phonemes that are significant in their own language. So much so that if a ***non-Anglophone*** articulates something using a completely different technique to native speakers, but the actual ***sound*** is sufficiently similar, they might not even notice. But audio analysis software wouldn't have the same built-in biases, so it might be more likely to pick up such "errors".